# $30$ Sided Dice Problem. Interview Preparation.

Tags: probability, expected-value, dice, expectation-maximization

I came through this problem three years ago when I prepared for interview. Today when reviewing it, I still couldn't think out a mathematical way to solve it. Any help would be appreciated.

$4$ players roll a fair $30$-sided dice. Each of them rolls once and the $4$ numbers rolled are different. The $2$ individuals that rolled the biggest and small value will be in a team while the $2$ individuals who rolled the $2^{\text{nd}}$ and $3^{\text{rd}}$ smallest value will be on the opposite team. The team with the largest average wins and the loser has to pay the winners' average number (*for example, if the dice outcome is $27, 20, 15,$ and $11,$ then the people who get $27$ and $11$ get paid $19$*).

Q) If you are the first to roll, what number would you prefer to maximize your payout?

Comment: Wouldn't the answer be thirty, so you could maximize the average of the team you get? Or am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: 30 is also my guess. I have the same thought process as you. But if it is a 5-dided dice, then the answer should be 4 rather than 5.

Comment: By brute force, the answer seems to be 24, but I wish there was a straightforward elegant way to find the answer ( and I may be wrong because I try to work in Pari terminal from a lousy smartphone keyboard)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I get the same as you. 30 is worse than average, which surprised me. The worst number to pick is 7.

Comment: How did you guys get the 24?

Comment: @ggkkll I wrote a program to loop through all possible 4-tuples, work out how much the person with each number won or lost, and tally them up by number rolled. I don't think there's a simple mathematical way to get it.

Comment: The reason that $~30~$ is not correct is that it makes it certain that you will be paired with the worst roll.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple python program to find the answer:

```
from itertools import combinations
score=[0]*31
for x in combinations(range(1,31),4):
    outer=x[0]+x[3]
    inner=x[1]+x[2]
    if outer>inner:
        score[x[0]]+=outer
        score[x[1]]-=outer
        score[x[2]]-=outer
        score[x[3]]+=outer
    elif inner>outer:
        score[x[0]]-=inner
        score[x[1]]+=inner
        score[x[2]]+=inner
        score[x[3]]-=inner
for i in range(1,31):
    print(i,score[i],sep="\t")
```

I assumed that if both totals are equal no-one wins or loses anything. To avoid floats I also doubled everything (so that you win or lose the sum, rather than the average). The highest value is best; here that is 24.